# Help for center Geolocation Polygon Map with Leaflet?

Tags: hooks

Is somebody knows how to center a leaflet map with a geolocation polygon field?
I want to center the drawing of polygon like below but there is just few options which don't help me.

[image]

To reproduce :

1. Install Geolocation Project and All Demo
2. In admin/structure/types/manage/geolocation_geometry_demo/display , change the format of Geolocation Geometry Polygon in "Geolocation Geometry Formatter - Map" and Save.
3. Edit the content "Static Geolocation Geometry Demo - Wanaka NZ" and change the first Geolocation Geometry Polygon with this value : POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10)) and Save.
4. Now go to the content view and see that the map is not centered on Polygon but in the sea.

I try to change differents options in the display but nothing works.

Maybe it's possible to update the position of the map with hook_geolocation_field_map_widget_alter??

Thanks for your help.